# Get ID of next DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How do I get the ID of the element after a class that is clicked?

Comment: What do you mean by "after"?  First child?  Next sibling?  Please show a simple code snippet to clarify your meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".className").click(function() {
    $(this).next().attr("id");
});
```

1. `$(".className")`: select elements with class `className`
2. `.click()`: jQuery onclick handler
3. `$(this)`: selects element again
4. `.next()`: get next element
5. `.attr("id")`: retrieve `id` attribute

If you want to get it on click, add a `click()` handler

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't know that attr() existed, thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @user5919397 I'm glad I helped (just make sure to click the green check-mark to accept this answer to show that it helped you)!

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function to select the "immediately following sibling":

```
$(function() {
    $(".yourClassName").click(function() {
        let yourNextElementId = $(this).next().attr("id");
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't get the id.

Answer (score 1):

Use `next()` to get the next element and use `attr()` to get its ID":

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sample_class').click(function() {
    alert($(this).next().attr('id'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sample_class">element with class</div>
<div id="sample_id">next element with id</div>
```